# Limiting the width of image to screen width

Tags: android, image, width, screen

In my app, I am using an image. I do not want the width of image to exceed the width of the screen in any screen size of any density. How to achieve that and what will be issues as I am using only one image for all android densities instead of images of different resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

try this, but you will need  a resized image for each resolution

> hdpi, ldpi, mdpi and xdpi resolutions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/title_bar"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/YourPicSource" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is there any way to avoid this ? what "wrap_content" achieves ?

Comment: wrap_content is replaced by your real image width, if you want to make it on all of screen change wrap_content with match_parent or fill_parent i hope that help you